# Is it possible to find mobile number from a mail in the inbox using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email

I am working in asp.net, Is their any possibility to find Mobile number from a mail in the inbox without opening the mail. consider that

- All the mails in the inbox **having the same format**.
- all of them **having mobile number** in its body content
- and all them are in the format "**mob: 9874561230**"
- but the mobile number may very according to the sender

i had connected to the inbox using **Pop3Client** and i extract the mail content as string and text file, now i need to find the mobile number in it. does anyone can help me to find it?

help full support will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have the body of the e-mail as a string (as you mentioned) you could just simply use `string.SubString()` method combined with `string.IndexOf()` method.

E.g.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string mailBody = "some text in the mail body ...... mob: 9874561230 .... some text in the mail body ";
            string mobileNo = mailBody.Substring(mailBody.IndexOf("mob:")+5, 10);

            Console.WriteLine(mobileNo.Trim());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

LIMITATIONS

1. Mobile no should be 10 digits long
2. Should be in the mob: 9874561230 format
3. There shouldn't be "mob: " in anywhere in the body text other than when representing the mobile number

Hope this solves your issue

Cheers!

Comment: it is enough. am dealing with auto generated mails

Comment: Good! You could also have variable length and + sign in the mobile no. But, will have to do little bit more processing to get it filtered.

Comment: can i get 8th line of my mail as the input to this code

Comment: Yes, you can have any text given the conditions mentioned above are satisfied

Comment: i mean how to get the 8th line?

Comment: Ok, that's a different question :) Anyway, currently you have the entire body as a string. But, in binary world all lines are ending with carriage return/ new line character. So, use that to slit your string into a string array. Then by using the array index you could find the line you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: what i do am unable to post question

Comment: string[] lines = mailBody.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
//8th line will be in lines[7] if there are no blank lines in between

Comment: in the above segment where i specify the line number is 8

Comment: lines[7] gives you line 8. Because this string array starts from 0

Comment: Dim lines() As String = mailbody.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                mobile = lines(7).ToString().Substring(lines(7).ToString().IndexOf("MOB :") + 5, 10) result in **"Index was outside the bounds of the array."**

Comment: Post a sample string you get in mailbody variable

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to use some key to identify the position of the mobile number.

Ex: insert the number between 2 angular brackets. You can suggest your client to always insert the mobile number between angular brackets or some other  special characters.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string mailBody = "some text in the mail body ......<9874561230> .... some text in the mail body ";
        string mobileNo = mailBody.Substring(mailBody.IndexOf("<") + 1, mailBody.IndexOf(">") - mailBody.IndexOf("<")-1 );

        Console.WriteLine(mobileNo.Trim());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here you don't want to bother about the length of mobile number and the format.